# If formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My equation is:

```
=IF(B2>10,"129920",IF(B2>15,"350591",IF(B2>25,"498636",IF(B2>50,"752640",IF(B2>100,"1231889")))))
```

It's showing 129920 for all; not working properly even if B2 is 35, answer showing 129920 rather than 498636.

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine, just not like you intended ;-)

In your example (with B2 equal to 35), B2 > 10, so the first IF returns "129920" and will not fall through to the second, third IFs etc.

Reverse the order of your comparisons (i.e. start with the highest number) and it will work like you intended.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is working as written - `B2>10`. So, the first condition is TRUE,  129920 is shown.

I think if you read this you should be able to work it out, but the answer is: **reverse them**.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the explanation, but I would like to point out that nested if is in general hard to read and easy to make mistakes.

You can consider using IFS that cleans up the logic slightly

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

or even better, create a table containing the cut-off value and then use Xlookup or Vlookup with match mode set to -1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

The future you will thank you for making your excel sheet more traceable and tidy

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(B2>10,B2<=15),"129920",IF(AND(B2>15,B2<=25),"350591",IF(AND(B2>25,B2<=50),"498636",IF(AND(B2>50,B2<=100),"752640",IF(B2>100,"1231889")))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn’t really improve upon the other answers you’ve already been given, it just shows a way that I find makes the formula more readable.  A year from now when I have to edit the rules, it will be easier to do because I made the formula as readable as possible.

If you have access to the LET formula, I am using it more and more for longer formulas, and using alt-enter to create a readable line-break format when I do.

So my approach would be more like:

```
=LET(
a, {0, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100},
b, {0, 129920, 350591, 498636, 752640, 1231889},
XLOOKUP( B2, a, b, 0, -1) )
```